# Approaching singleton connection class

Tags: c#, asp.net, singleton

```
    namespace AV.Connections
{

    protected class MyConnection
    {

        protected ConnectionStringSettings connectionSettings
        {
            get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySQLConnection"]; }
        }

        protected DbConnection connection
        {
            get { return new OdbcConnection(connectionSettings.ConnectionString); }
        }

        protected DbCommand command
        {
            get { return connection.CreateCommand(); }
        }

        protected DbParameter parameter
        {
            get { return command.CreateParameter(); }
        }

    }
}
```

I was trying to create singleton class which could return connection objects as well as other related objects. The above was the approach I thought of. I am sure I am wrong somehow. Please point out the how? Or if not what's the best approach for this.

This is not Singleton....I understand but I think I can't declare the class static as it involves connections. So I am really confused about this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a singleton (unless it's accessed through a factory class with responsbility to maintain only one instance of this class). Check out this article for how to implement the singleton pattern: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx